# Is "surface" used as a noun?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Do not be surprised to see the same apprehension **surface** inside the EU itself.

<sup>([Source: The Economist: Eastern Europeans think Western food brands are selling them dross](https://www.economist.com/news/europe/21724408-dual-foods-furore-hints-eastern-mistrust-west-eastern-europeans-think-western-food))</sup>

Comment: It is used as a verb here; see [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/surface), 6.

Comment: But why it isn't surfaces when apprehension is singular?

Comment: It's an infinitive, as complement of *see*: "I saw him **go**", "We saw the sun **rise**", "You will see apprehension **surface**".

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, but not in this case.

Firstly, yes, "surface" can be used as a noun. "The leaf floats on the **surface** of the water".

Secondly, your example sentence uses it as a verb. (Maybe you used the wrong word in your title by mistake?)

Thirdly, to answer your further question in the comments:

> But why it isn't surfaces when apprehension is singular?

There are two reasons.

1. "Apprehension" is the **object** of the verb. The verb must agree with the **subject**.
2. The *main* verb in the sentence is "be [surprised]". "To see" is its **complement** (an "infinitive clause"). In its turn, "surface" is the complement of "to see", so it also stays in the infinitive form.

If my point #1 above made you wonder, "What is the subject?", it's not actually stated. The verb "be" is used as an imperative, so there is an implied subject of "you".

Maybe this will help?

> The apprehension surfaces. *(The only time "surface" gets conjugated.)*
>
> You see the apprehension surface.
>
> You are not surprised to see the apprehension surface.
>
> Do not be surprised to see the apprehension surface.